# Saving javascript code inside database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've very annoying problem with hosting of well known company however

I've website and at its back-end there is form has `textarea` field where it should be for `google adsense code` when i submit it does not respond at all and keep loading

but when i type anything else then `adsense ads code` it accepted so i noticed it not allowing for html

**Form code**

```
<form method=post action="1.php" name="adsense" id="adsense">

The Code : <textarea id="ad" name="ad">Put your code here</textarea>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">

</form>
```

**1.php Code**

```
<?PHP

include "header.php"; // connect to db

if(isset($_POST[submit])){

$qma = "update webads set
ad = '$_POST[ad]'";

$rma = mysql_query($qma) or die(mysql_error());
echo 'Thanks';

}

?>
```

**The problem** when i put `adsense ads code` it not respond and not save it in database but if i put any text it save it normally

so i've been thinking to `addslashes()` but it also didn't worked after i made such changes

```
ad1 = 'addslashes($_POST[ad1])'
```

here is example of unaccepted `google adsense code`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google_ad_client = "pub-0000000000000000";
google_ad_width = 250;
google_ad_height = 250;
google_ad_format = "250x250_as";
google_ad_type = "text";
google_ad_channel = "0000000000";
google_color_border = "FFFCE1";
google_color_bg = "FFFCE1";
google_color_link = "FFFCE1";
google_color_text = "FFFCE1";
google_color_url = "FFFCE1";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
```

One last note

the database field structure is `text NOT NULL`

```
CREATE TABLE `webads` (
`id` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
`ad` text NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`))";
```

so any idea how to save it ! but it must be easy to recall it back without being altered

i don't know if it stupid or not but if i didn't got any answer how to do it, been thinking to `base_64 encoder` before save it then when i call it back will `base_64 decode` it but this sound last hope i can do

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think it should be: ad1 = addslashes($_POST[ad1]); . That's what you meant...right?

Comment: if(isset($_POST[s1])) from where you are getting s1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `htmlentities` before storing data to database.
and you can't use function inside string.

```
$ad = htmlentities($_POST['ad']);
```

Also when using `addslashes` you'd better first check if it's automatically enabled by server configuration, not to over-quote strings. See [get_magic_quotes_gpc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php)

```
if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $ad = addslashes($ad);
} 

...

$qma = "update webads set ad = '$ad'";
```

Comment: Guess What! i tried all methods and still not working but noticed that if i enter even something like this <script>xxx</script> it not save it !! so it might be refer to hosting company itself .. it is godaddy and paid not free hosting :( have you any idea about such problem

Comment: You should avoid writing data which includes html tags to database especially `script` so if you escape html entities everything goes fine. Next time when you want reverse function, I mean when you have to output that code you can use `html_entity_decode`:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the posted variable for MySQL - the best way to do this is to use PHP's built in function as it will do it correctly for your version of MySQL

```
$qma = "update webads set ad = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[ad]) . "'";
```

Comment: Guess What! i tried all methods and still not working but noticed that if i enter even something like this <script>xxx</script> it not save it !! so it might be refer to hosting company itself .. it is godaddy and paid not free hosting :( have you any idea about such problem

Comment: Does it not save anything at all? or just strip out the <script> tags? It could be some kind of security measure but I wouldn't expect it on paid hosting. Try hard coding an sql statement to insert it and see if that works.

`$qma = "update webads set ad = '<script>TEST</script>'"`

Comment: `$qma = "update webads set ad = '<script>TEST</script>'"` not saving it and after many tries i found if the input text as <script> or </script> or <script ....> it never save just keep loading then say page not found .. yes i think it is kind of secuirty measure so i'm going to try my luck with `$ad = base64_encode($_POST['ad']);` then try to update it.

Comment: oh my lord even if `base64_encode()` `<script>` it not save it !! it did only after i strip `<` and `>` !! very annoying hosting even seen in my life

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you can use

```
$ad = htmlspecialchars($_POST['ad']);

$qma = "update webads set ad = '$ad'";
```

Answer (score 0):

When I work with MySQL Workbench and I do something like `update webads set
ad = '$_POST[ad]'` it throws an error because of the safe mode. My SQL query doesn't have an ID. Maybe the safe mode is on?

If you want to bypass it, just add `WHERE ID != -1` but I don't recommend doing this.

Don't forget to sanitize your input.